# React Native - React-native-app-auth - service_configuration_fetch_error

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

### Environment

- **Your Identity Provider**: `Azure`
- **Platform that you're experiencing the issue on**: `Android`
- **Are you using Expo?**: `No`
- **React Native Version**: `0.66.4`
- **React Native App Auth Version**: `6.4.0`

Hi Folks,

My app is being used by about 300 users and we are getting a lot of complaints about problems logging into Microsoft using MFA.

After receiving the SMS and adding the code, the user confirms on the consent screen to be redirected back to the app but often he goes back to the Microsoft Login page.

The problem can be solved palliatively by clearing the cache of the Chrome app.

I put some logs on my AppCenter:

[image]

Below is what my code looks like:

[image]

And my Azure Url Redirect configuration on App Register:

[image]

**Question:**
I need to put on property appAuthRedirectScheme the same name of my bundleId? Or can I put any custom string?

And

What could be the problem on service_configuration_fetch_error?

Comment: Please provide more information such as the stack trace of Azure AD debug information (request id, correlation id and timestamp).

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Could it be that this is just a temporary issue due to a poor Internet connection? 
I have seen the same issue come up in our logs and the same users have been able to successfully log in after a couple of attempts. 
Can you see if the users having this error have managed to log in at all?
(We have the exact same set-up: React Native: 0.66.3, React Native App Auth: 6.4.1, MFA with Microsoft and we have seen this log on Android)